# How does the pseudosphere relate to other models in hyperbolic geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

It's familiar to me that the pseudosphere has local hyperbolic geometry (locally is isomorphic to a hyperbolic plane).

I am not very sure what is precisely presented in these pictures.

Also, I am interested in some examples of how the pseudosphere is related to the hyperbolic plane.

What I have is that the hyperbolic plane and pseudosphere have the same Gaussian curvature ($K = -1$), so they are locally isometric.

Any comments will be welcome.

[image]

Comment: Please learn to write an *informative* title.  Phrases such as "can someone please help me understand..." are vacuous;  of *course* you need help understanding something... that's why you're asking a question!  And can't you be more explicit and precise about "picture"?  (Just *one*, by the way?)  Might some readers expect to see you holding a puppy, for instance?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sorry, I am a beginner. Better now?

Comment: Yes... a bit better.  (I'll eliminate the -1.)

Comment: @smth: what book are these sourced from?

Comment: @Narasimham these are from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere

Answer (score 3):

You are correct about the local isometry.

The other three models show ways of mapping the hyperbolic plane bijectively, but *not* isometrically, onto an open subset of the Euclidean plane. They are analogous to map projections. In both cases, it is impossible to map the source (hyperbolic plane, or portion of the globe) isometrically onto the target because the curvatures are different, and curvature is an isometric invariant.

To help you compare the different models, they have picked one to draw a grid on, and shown what corresponds to it in the other models. In other words, they have mapped the grid to the hyperbolic plane, and mapped it back down to another model. They have also depicted a couple of geodesics (the green and blue curves). The vertical lines in the upper half plane are also geodesics. (I would consider them analogous to meridians in, say, the Mercator projection: these are also geodesic, and are depicted as vertical lines.)

The grid does *not* consist of equal sized squares according to the hyperbolic metric. It’s just there as a visual aid.

The mapping to the pseudosphere *is* a locally isometry. The drawbacks are (1) the target is a surface in 3D, instead of being a subset of the Euclidean plane, (2) the mapping cannot be continued past the rim, even though there is more hyperbolic plane “past it”, and (3) the topology is wrong: the hyperbolic plane is simply connected, but the pseudosphere has nontrivial loops.

Comment: Very nice answer. On other thing I'll throw in: the Klein disc model is the projective image of what our eye would actually see *if* we lived in 3-dimensional hyperbolic space and we were looking down from above at a 2-dimensional hyperbolic plane.

Comment: A few more observations: The dark brown curve is a horocycle, which can be seen from both the upper half plane and Poincare disk models. From the picture of the pseudosphere, it appears that the rim is a horocycle. The light brown and light blue curves are definitely geodesics. It's less obvious to me that the green and dark blue curves are geodesics, but it's plausible. Also, in the upper half plane model they could have drawn the vertical grid lines (geodesics) with a different color than the horizontal lines (horocycles).

Comment: @Deane I think it's pretty clear that if the blue and green circular arcs were extended to meet "infinity" in the upper plane model, they would meet it orthogonally, so they're geodesics. While I agree about the grid, they did draw two light brown vertical lines, to emphasize their geodesic status.